Blocking OCSP url while signing Baseline LT
We use iText.Signatures.PdfPadesSigner class in a .net project to sign Baseline-LT and this class enforce to verify OCSP first then optionally CRL.
If the Certificate doesn’t have an OCSP url then the class will verify LTV using crls.
But if the certificate has an OCSP it will verify OCSP first.
The issue happens when we try to block OCSP url on our local machine as a test case, the signing process stopped completely and throws exception that it can’t get neither OCSPs or CRLs.
Is there a solution to overcome that or shall we use another library?

How did you "try to block OCSP url on your local machine"?

@mkl by adding the ocsp url to the hosts file and giving it IP 127.0.0.1 so it can’t go to the real ip

So it queries the url on the local host. Is there a web server listening on the port from the ocsp url on that local host?

We don’t specialize a port for the ocsp domain name. We use this way only to try to block the ocsp so we can simulate that the ocsp real service is not reachable and handle this case in our code. By the way I found a solution for my quuestion and I’ll share it here soon.

I found another way to over come that. I used PdfSigner class instead of PdfPadesSigner to sign timestamp basically and send LTV data separately.
I used this method from it SignDetached(IExternalSignature externalSignature, IX509Certificate[] chain, ICollection<ICrlClient> crlList, IOcspClient ocspClient, ITSAClient tsaClient, int estimatedSize, CryptoStandard sigtype)
set crlList = null, ocspClient = null and sigtype = CADES and send the other values as normal.
Then, I added LTV data using class LtvVerification specifically this method AddVerification(string signatureName, IOcspClient ocsp, ICrlClient crl, CertificateOption certOption, Level level, CertificateInclusion certInclude), so I can control which level I need instead of being forced to use PdfPadesSigner choosed level.
I set level = OCSP_CRL
When the OCSP is blocked this level will enable checking CRL without throwing exceptions

The LtvVerification class by default has a RevocationDataNecessity of OPTIONAL while PdfPadesSigner uses an instance with a necessity of REQUIRED_FOR_SIGNING_CERTIFICATE, and only with the latter value the exception you mention is thrown if no revocation data are retrieved. In your case, therefore, possibly neither OCSP responses nor CRLs could be retrieved and your solution merely deactivates the test that PdfPadesSigner enforces.

You don't mention the CertificateOption value you use. If you don't use CertificateOption.ALL_CERTIFICATES, this may also explain why you get no exception with your solution.

For PdfPadesSigner your explanation may be right but for LtvVerification although RevocationDataNecessity is OPTIONAL, but it can retrieve CRLs. The reason for that is the Level used OCSP_OPTIONAL_CRL enforces to get OCSP if there is an OCSP URL and if it can't get it, exception will be thrown.
OCSP_CRL level doesn't enforce to retrieve OCSP, so it can skip OCSP if it can't retrieve it.

I used CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN

WHOLE_CHAIN only includes the signer certificate and its chain. ALL_CERTIFICATES (as used by the PdfPadesSigner) also includes the time stamp unit certificate and its chain. The issue might occur for the tsu certificate, not at all for the signer certificate.

"The reason for that is the Level used OCSP_OPTIONAL_CRL enforces to get OCSP if there is an OCSP URL and if it can't get it, exception will be thrown." - OCSP_OPTIONAL_CRL and OCSP_CRL operate very similarly: First both attempt to retrieve an OCSP response. Thereafter, both (the latter always and the former only if no OCSP response was retrieved) try to retrieve a CRL. Thus, OCSP_OPTIONAL_CRL  can also retrieve a CRL. And the exception you described is only thrown if neither OCSP response nor CRL has been retrieved and the necessity is REQUIRED_FOR_SIGNING_CERTIFICATE.
